# email-based registration using oauth2 flow possible?

Tags: security, oauth-2.0

Is it possible to implement the Oauth2 flow in which , instead of a specific identity provider being used in the redirect, you instead ask the user to submit an email address, and then send an authorization code to that email address, and they click the link to get issued an access token?

In this scenario, how would one make use of a state parameter to prevent CSRF?  And, are there other security implications to this design?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a custom grant type ([example](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/multifactor-resource-owner-password)). Translation: this will be a scheme that is proprietary to your clients and your authorization server. You're either going to have to write a lot of code yourself or rely on a commercial solution such as one linked above. Your clients will have to understand this flow...so you won't be able to grab any oAuth-compliant app and expect that it'll work with this scheme.

A better option is to NOT go through email and NOT require a user entry of an additional authentication factor. Instead, use one of the standard grant types with a well-defined threat model. Recommendation: authorization code grant type with PKCE extension. It takes care of CSRF and many other threat vectors. See [oAuth Security Best Current Practice (BCP)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13) for more details.

As an alternative, you can perform your email-based verification routine after the oAuth flow is done.

Comment: Interesting.  So, to implement PMCE, what query parameters should the link in the email contain?  My first guess would be:  response_type=code, code_challenge=<...>, code_challenge_method=<...>.  but, then, would it be the javascript in the web browser that generates the challenge + verifier?

Comment: Standard oAuth flows (incl. authorization grant type with or without PKCE) do not go through disconnected clients such as email. You'll need an app with a service endpoint that receives oAuth messages, you won't be able to manufacture a link.